# How to change the contents of spinner on run time in Android

Tags: android, spinner

Can anybody help me to change the contents of spinner on run time in Android.

Examples would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the adapter which is bound to the Spinner. Either you edit add or remove items to/from the adapter and refresh it or you create a new adapter filled with the new items and bind it to the Spinner.